# Can set properties be demonstrated only with symbols?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying sets and I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to demonstrate properties. I would like to know if there is a way to do it without having to write text (like 'since' and 'in particular'), and only using symbols. To illustrate it I'll put my last exercise, and also I would like to know if it is correct:

$$A \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow A \cap B = A$$

So I have to prove this:

1) $A \subseteq B \Rightarrow A \cap B = A$

> Hypothesis: $X \in A \Rightarrow X \in B$

So to prove it, I have to prove double inclusion.

1.1) $A \cap B \subseteq A$

1.2) $A \subseteq A \cap B$

2) $A \cap B = A \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$

> Hypothesis: $X \in A \wedge X \in B \Rightarrow X \in A$

Then I did the following:

> 1.1) $A \cap B \subseteq A$

$A \cap B \subseteq A \Rightarrow X \in A \wedge X \in B$

$\Rightarrow X \in A$ *in particular*

$\Rightarrow A \cap B \subseteq A$

> 1.2) $A \subseteq A \cap B$

$X \in A \Rightarrow X \in A \wedge X \in A$

$\Rightarrow X \in A \wedge X \in B$ *by hypothesis from 1)*

$\Rightarrow X \in A \cap B$

> 2) $A \cap B = A \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$

$X \in A \Rightarrow X \in A \wedge X \in B$ *conmutative $A = A \cap B$*

since $X \in B$ *in particular*

$\Rightarrow A \subseteq B$

Comment: Would you explain why you do not want to write text in your proofs, please? This may help potential *answerers*.

Comment: @Timon I only want to know if this can be done to have a more solid step by step answer. Also to understand how text can be replaced by symbols, which would give me a more deep knowledge of the theory. But if it is recommended to use text, then I have no problem. I just want to know the standard

Comment: The less words you use the more unreadable and cryptic the result. For instance, what does the mysterious "commutative" in the line following item 2) mean?

Comment: If your interest in getting rid of text is that you want a "completely formal" proof, you should have a look at formal proof systems, such as natural deduction or sequent calculus.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo thanks. What I've tried to say is that $A = A \cap B  and  A \cap B = A$. I get your point. I will stick with this method since I'm not a mathematician and it doesn't seem to be that simple to replace the text. Is my exercise correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\subset B\iff [\;\forall x\;(x\in A\implies x\in B)\;]\iff [\;\forall x\;(x\in A\implies [x\in B\land x\in A])\;]\iff$$     $$[\;\forall x\;(\;(x\in A\implies [x\in B\land x\in A])\land ([x\in B\land x\in A]\implies x\in A)\;)\;]\iff$$ $$[\; \forall x\;(x\in A\iff (x\in B\land  x\in A)\;] \iff [\;\forall x\;(x\in A\iff x\in A\cap B)\;]\iff$$ $$A=A\cap B.$$

The justification for the second line is that $[x\in B\land x\in A]\implies x\in A$ is a truism.

Comment: Imagine an entire textbook written this way.:)

Comment: Ok I get it lol. Is my exercise correct?

Comment: yes it's correct. I wanted to see if I could put it all into one sentence with no words.